# What are the steps to remove reimageplus virus manually?

Tags: windows, virus, malware, virus-removal, malware-removal

What are the steps to remove reimageplus virus manually(as in without using any third party software)? I tried using adwcleaner but it seems to keep coming back or something. How to completely remove it?

I am on Windows 7. I don't know it got contracted.

Comment: "adwcleaner" is third-party software.  Is there a reason you don't want to use tools designed to remove malicious software?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it is, which proved wasn't potent in this particular virus. I don't want to lose those tools for having a better understanding of what's going on on my pc.

Comment: My research indicates this malware is a browser-based infection which means, the removal of your browser profile, should be enough to remove it.  I suggest just using better quality security software, which can detect this particular variation, and take note of what actions were performed.

Comment: What operation system are you running, exactly? Do you know how you contracted the virus? Are you starting in a state of the operating system running, or from a shut-down computer? etc.

Comment: @einpoklum I do not understand your last question.